# How to change the alignment on materialize

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

i am using the materialize framework for my front-end design but when its load initially all looks good but when i return to index there comes the problem with the alignment when i clear the cookies it looks good[image]

This is how its looking

[image]

This is the orginal Expected Output.

Can anyone help to resolve the Issuie

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/') ?>css/materialize.css" rel="stylesheet">
     
      <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/') ?>css/slippry.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/logo/favicon.ico'); ?>" type="image/x-icon">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/'); ?>js/materialize.js"></script>
    <title>Tolle Exam No.1 Exam Platform for Nursing Exam | RAILWAY Exam</title>
    </head>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
.morecontent span {
    display: none;
}
.morelink {
    display: block;
}
nav ul li:hover {
   background-color:    #00ffbf;
}
  
.input-field input:focus + label {
   color: orange !important;
 }
 .input-field input:focus {
   border-bottom: 1px solid orange !important;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 orange !important
 }
 #viewMore{
  display: none;
 }
 
.dropdown-content {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
  min-width: 300px; /* Changed this to accomodate content width */
  max-height: auto;
  margin-left: -1px; /* Add this to keep dropdown in line with edge of navbar */
  overflow: hidden; /* Changed this from overflow-y:auto; to overflow:hidden; */
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 1;
  will-change: width, height;
}


#hv:hover{
border-radius: 1px solid blue;
}
</style>
    <body oncontextmenu="return false;">

      <!-- Dropdown Structure -->

<!-- <ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
  <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('exam/12'); ?>" class="black-text">ALL</a></li>
  <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('exam/12'); ?>" class="black-text">JEE MAIN</a></li>
  <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('exam/12'); ?>" class="black-text">KERALA PSC</a></li>
  <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('exam/12'); ?>" class="black-text">RAILWAY EXAMS</a></li>
</ul>
<nav style="height: 80px; padding: 10px;" class="white">
  <div class="nav-wrapper ">
    <a href="<?php echo base_url(''); ?>" class="brand-logo black-text">Logo</a>
    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('institutions'); ?>" class="black-text">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-trigger black-text" href="#!" data-target="dropdown1">Competative Exams<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('institutions'); ?>" class="black-text">Institution Exams</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('institutions'); ?>" class="black-text">Notifications</a></li>
      
      <li><a  href="<?php echo base_url('login'); ?>" class="btn btn-large orange lighten-2" title="" style="border-radius: 30px;">Login / Register <i class="material-icons right">lock</i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav> -->


<nav style="height: 100px; padding: 15px;" class="white">
    <div class="nav-wrapper white darken-3">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>" class="brand-logo  black-text" style="padding-left:25px;"><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/logo/tolle_logo2.png'); ?>" style="height:80px;" alt="logo"></a>
        <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse black-text"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(''); ?>" class="black-text" >Home</a></li>
            <li><a id="hv" class="dropdown-button black-text" href="#!" data-activates="dropdown" data-beloworigin="true">Competitive Exams<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
            <li><a id="hv" href="<?php echo base_url('ins_view'); ?>" class="black-text">Institution Exams</a></li>
            <li><a id="hv" href="<?php echo base_url('notification/show_notification1'); ?>" class="black-text">Notifications</a></li>
            <!-- Dropdown Trigger --> 
            <?php if($_SESSION['logged_in']==FALSE){ ?>

            <a  href="<?php echo base_url('login'); ?>" class="btn btn-large orange lighten-2" title="" style="border-radius: 30px;">Login / Register <i class="material-icons right">lock</i></a>
          <?php }else{ ?>
           <a class="black-text" title="Dashboard" href="<?php echo base_url('admin/dashboard'); ?>">Welcome: <?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?></a>
<a  href="<?php echo base_url('logout'); ?>" class="btn btn-large orange lighten-2" title="" style="border-radius: 30px;">Logout <i class="material-icons right">lock_open</a>
        <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>

</nav>
<ul id="dropdown" class="dropdown-content collection">
    <li class="collection-item">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url('exam/ALL'); ?>" >
        <span class="title black-text">ALL EXAMS</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <?php foreach($categories as $cat): ?>
    <li class="collection-item">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url('exam/'.$cat['name']); ?>" >
        <span class="title black-text"><?php echo $cat['name']; ?></span>
      </a>
    </li>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url(''); ?>" class="black-text" >Home</a></li>
           
            </li>
            <ul class="collapsible">
            <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i>Competitive Exams</div>
    <?php foreach($categories as $cat): ?>
    <div class="collapsible-body">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url('exam/'.$cat['name']); ?>" >
        <span class="title blue-text" ><?php echo $cat['name']; ?></span>
      </a>
          </div>
          <?php endforeach; ?></li></ul>
            <li><a id="hv" href="<?php echo base_url('ins_view'); ?>" class="black-text">Institution Exams</a></li>
            <li><a id="hv" href="<?php echo base_url('notification/show_notification1'); ?>" class="black-text">Notifications</a></li>
            <!-- Dropdown Trigger --> 
            <?php if($_SESSION['logged_in']==FALSE){ ?>

            <a  href="<?php echo base_url('login'); ?>" class="btn btn-large orange lighten-2" title="" style="border-radius: 30px;">Login / Register <i class="material-icons right">lock</i></a>
          <?php }else{ ?>
           <a class="black-text" title="Dashboard" href="<?php echo base_url('admin/dashboard'); ?>">Welcome: <?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?></a>
 <li></li><a  href="<?php echo base_url('logout'); ?>" class="btn btn-large orange lighten-2" title="" style="border-radius: 30px;">Logout <i class="material-icons right">lock_open</a>
        <?php } ?>
  </ul>
<!-- Dropdown Structure -->
```

Above is my Header File

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/') ?>js/slippry.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/') ?>js/readmore.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Configure/customize these variables.
    var showChar = 100;  // How many characters are shown by default
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "Show more >";
    var lesstext = "Show less";
    

    $('.more').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();
 
        if(content.length > showChar) {
 
            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);
 
            var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';
 
            $(this).html(html);
        }
 
    });
 
    $(".morelink").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
<script>
  (function($) {
    $(function() {
      $('#article').readmore({
        speed: 75,
        lessLink: '<a href="#">Read less</a>'
      });
$('.dropdown-button').dropdown({
      inDuration: 300,
      outDuration: 225,
      hover: true, // Activate on hover
      belowOrigin: true, // Displays dropdown below the button
      alignment: 'right' // Displays dropdown with edge aligned to the left of button
    }
  );

    }); // End Document Ready
})(jQuery); // End of jQuery name space
</script>
<?php 
if( $this->session->flashdata('msg') ){
 ?>
<?php echo '<script>Materialize.toast("'.$this->session->flashdata('msg').'", 3000)</script>' ?>
<?php } ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown-trigger").dropdown();
     $('.carousel.carousel-slider').carousel();
      $('.collapsible').collapsible();
    $('.button-collapse').sideNav();
    $('.modal').modal();
 $("#trigg").click(function(){
    $("#viewMore").slideToggle("slow");
  });
     });
</script>


<script>
//   count=0;
// $(document).ready(function() {
//   var hidden, visibilityState, visibilityChange;

//   if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") {
//     hidden = "hidden", visibilityChange = "visibilitychange", visibilityState = "visibilityState";
//   } else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
//     hidden = "msHidden", visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange", visibilityState = "msVisibilityState";
//   }

//   var document_hidden = document[hidden];

//   document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, function() {
//     if(document_hidden != document[hidden]) {
//       if(document[hidden]) {
//         // Document hidden
//         alert('hidden');
//         count++;
//       } else {
//         // Document shown
//         alert('Revoked');
//         if(count ==3){
//           alert('Exceeded the Limit');
//         }
//       }

//       document_hidden = document[hidden];
//     }
//   });
// });
</script>




<script>
    function startExam(url) {
  params  = 'width='+screen.width;
 params += ', height='+screen.height;
 params += ', top=0, left=0'
 params += ', fullscreen=yes';
 params += ', directories=no';
 params += ', location=no';
 params += ', menubar=no';
 params += ', resizable=no';
 params += ', scrollbars=no';
 params += ', status=no';
 params += ', toolbar=no';
 params += ', resizable=no';


 newwin=window.open(url,'FullWindowAll', params);
 if (window.focus) {newwin.focus()}
 return false;
}

jQuery('#out-of-the-box-demo').slippry();


</script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modal').modal();
  });
</script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

THis is the footer

Comment: sorry for missing the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

Some tags are not closed properly.
Somewhere closed `</li>` tag on the wrong position and somewhere you missed to closing `</a>` tags.